# Is there a way you can change the material of another object from your script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried using getcomponent to interchange the material of two cubes when the player cube collides with the other but im getting errors i dont know what i did wrong.

```
 public Material[] material;
 Material x;
 Material y;
 Material tempholder;
 Renderer rend;

 GameObject otherobj;
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
     rend.enabled = true;
     rend.sharedMaterial = x;
     otherobj = y;
 }
 private void Awake()
 {
     otherobj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Box");
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {
     if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Box")
     {
         otherobj.GetComponent<Material>();
         tempholder=x;
         x = y;
         y = tempholder;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `but im getting errors` What errors? Please specify.

Comment: `otherobj.GetComponent<Material>();` and material is never a component...

Comment: Material is a property of the MeshRenderer component

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: @KaenbyouRin it doesn't show me any errors in the code but when i click on play it tells me to fix compiler errors

Comment: @KaenbyouRin i already did that but how can i change the material of the obj with the material of the obj that collided with it?

Comment: @LeoBartkus thanks that helped i was confused :))

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica oh sorry I just made my account still finding my way around here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Changemat : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.transform.CompareTag("Box"))
        {
            Material tempMat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = tempMat;
        }
    }
}
```

It was this easy and I was losing my head over this